# Can't get the proper default route

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I have 8 remote raspberry pi computers with wheezy and jessie installed. I am running all of them headless and currently connect via WiFi. They all have Edimax WiFi dongles installed. I am using both IPv4 and IPv6. When they boot I have the following output.

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:1d:09:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.13/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:db8::2:13/64 scope global tentative
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:1f:02:9b:d1:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::821f:2ff:fe9b:d1f4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.13
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.13
```

and here is the /etc/network/interface:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# WAN wlan0 should always be ready with a server static address
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    up fixroutes.sh
    up /usr/local/sbin/fixroutes.sh
iface wlan0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8::1:13
    netmask 64
    gateway 2001:db8::2

# Ethernet 0 interface is static for a server IPv4
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    down /usr/local/sbin/fixroutes.sh
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8::2:13
    netmask 64
```

Fixroutes contains:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

How do I get a default route added? I have tried without the up or down in the interfaces file, with the route add default in the interfaces file and also in the fixroutes file in the /etc/network/if-up.d directory.

Also, if I am allowed a second question, why did the IPv6 address for wlan0 not appear?

Thanks